# Is it possible to prevent Ionic from hiding previous page?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Ionic 3 applies "hidden" property to previous page when it navigates to the next page with navCtrl.push. Is it possible to prevent it from applying this property?

I know that I can select the previous page element and change the "display" property but I would like to know if there is an Ionic way to to that.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do this? I think it's generally not a good idea to 'work against' the framework you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that what I really need is to add a custom page transition instead of modifying the default navigation.
These two posts shows what I wanted to achieve:

https://www.joshmorony.com/create-a-custom-modal-page-transition-animation-in-ionic/

https://rafalradziszewski.pl/blog/ionic-custom-transitions

Thanks to @phonolog for warning me about "working against" the framework I'm using.